# Do WATIN support Selenium GRID Concepts?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watin, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2, selenium-server

I am trying to launch IE through Remote Web Driver and then attaching it to Watin.
Since some controls are not been identified by Web Driver, so i switched to watin and it works well. but in Grid Concept am not sure whether it would support, i cant able to attach.
Since Remote Driver is been used i have to launch it using the Web Driver and then move it to Watin. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Grid Concept?" Do you mean Grid Views in an ASP.NET WebForms application created by the `<asp:GridView />` tag? Or do you mean [Selenium-Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) allowing you to run multiple tests on multiple machines?

Comment: No Greg I did not mean that. Selenium Grid means communication between hub and node

Comment: What do you mean by "communication between hub and node?" You mean communication between two web applications? Between the Selenium server and the browser it's driving?

Comment: Yes, i meant communication between Selenium server(hub) and the browser (from other node using remote web driver) it's driving. I have done by launching  in Firefox using Selenium script but am not able to proceed it with WATIN once launching it in Internet Explorer. I need to attach the browser currently in web driver to IE(watin)

Comment: WatiN is a replacement for Selenium. Why would you need to use both? You should be able to use Selenium. Can you describe more about why you need WatiN to integrate with Selenium?

Comment: When Clicks  in Selenium is not possible Watin is preferred when IE browser is used.